# Laravel/Lumen не скачивается composer require illuminate/mail

Tags: laravel, sendmail, lumen

При выполнений команды: `composer require illuminate/mail`

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires illuminate/mail ^9.48 -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[v9.48.0, 9.x-dev].
    - illuminate/mail[v9.48.0, ..., 9.x-dev] require illuminate/collections ^9.0 -> found illuminate/collections[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v8.83.27 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require illuminate/mail:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require illuminate/mail:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

выходит это ошибка
и дальше при выполнений `php artisan make:mail Mail` не видит  Mailable класс
и `view` метод

пробовал скачать конкретные версий но там тоже примерно такие ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился командой `composer require illuminate/mail "*" -W`